# How can I take two matrices as input

Tags: python, matrix, addition

In this code I'm suppose to find the addition of the matrices. `A+B`

```
[[x + y for x,y in zip(w,v)] for w,v in zip(A,B)]
```

When I run the program and write in the python shell `A+B` The answer comes out as [[7, 4], [5, 0], [4, 4], [2, 2], [-3, 3], [-2, 4]]

The answer should actually be `[[9,6],[2,3],[2,8]]`

What do I need to integrate in the program so the Python function called `def addition (A,B)` takes the two matrices as input and return with the addition of the two input as the result.

Comment: ...it already does that. Just move the definition of `A` and `B` at the top to be below the function definition for clarity and call `addition(A, B)`.

Comment: When you write `A+B` in the interpreter, you're simply concatenating the lists. Do what @Dougal said and call your function. If you want to override the built in `+` you're looking for operator overloading, which dspyz mentioned (I'm guessing you aren't. That'd be weird homework).

Comment: How do I call my function?

Comment: @Jett `C = addition(A, B)`

Comment: Dougal was right I just needed to call the function. I thought I had to type `A+B` then the answer will appear. Nope reading the homework again I just had to call the function. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Or if you're not afraid of nested list comprehensions, you can do this with a one-liner

```
C = [[x + y for x,y in zip(w,v)] for w,v in zip(A,B)]
```

Comment: Well this is actually homework so I'm restricted to do it that way.

Comment: In that case your answer seems fine.  I tried running your code and got the correct result.  Are you looking for operator overloading?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to overload the operator `+` for your matrices you have to wrap the 2 dimensional list into a class and `def` the method `__add__`. For example (I use your addition function):

```
>>> class Matrix(object):
    @staticmethod
    def addition (A, B):
        d=[]
        n=0
        while n < len(B):
            c = []
            k = 0
            while k < len (A[0]):
                c.append(A[n][k]+B[n][k])
                k=k+1
            n+=1
            d.append(c)
        return d
    def __init__(self,lst):
        self.lst=lst
    def __add__(self, other):
        return Matrix(Matrix.addition(self.lst, other.lst))
    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.lst)


>>> A=Matrix([[7,4], [5,0], [4,4]])
>>> B=Matrix([[2,2], [-3,3], [-2, 4]])
>>> A+B
[[9, 6], [2, 3], [2, 8]]
```